# What is the best way to scrape this HTML for an android app?

Tags: java, android, screen-scraping, web-scraping, jsoup

What is the best way to scrape the below HTML from a web page?  I want to pull out Apple, Orange and Grape and put them into a dropdown menu in my Android app.  Should I use Jsoup for this, and if so, what would be the best way to do it?  Should I use Regex instead?

```
<select name="fruit" id="fruit" >
<option value="APPLE">Apple</option>
<option value="ORANGE">Orange</option>
<option value="GRAPE">Grape</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Depends, but I'd go with an XML/HTML parser. [Don't use regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Example with [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/):

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(someUrl).get();
Elements options = doc.select("select#fruit option");
```

[More on jsoup selector syntax](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax).

---

### Best way?

I would go with either the built-in [DOM parser or SAX parser](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/parsers/package-summary.html). If you're going to be parsing a large document, SAX is faster. If the document is small, then there's not much difference. [More on SAX vs DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/689097/is-xpath-much-more-efficient-as-compared-to-dom-and-sax).

Answer (score 2):

For HTML parsing you can use jsoup. The usage is very easy and the API is great.

http://jsoup.org/

For me it worked great!

EDIT:
too slow :D 
skyuzo's post is great :)

Comment: Yeah but can it be used with Android and its compiler?

Comment: yes it can! I use it for an android app - sorry for the late answer

Answer (score 1):

WebView is your friend:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

It let's you grab html as a browser, and then you can do stuff with it. Take notice that it doensn't take into account javascript, so I hope that's plain html you have therem not some ajax fetched or js generated code :)

Comment: Thanks...skyuzo gave me the answer that I had in mind, but this is an interesting option and I'm definitely going to look into it.