# Extract tags from xml in string to array

Tags: java, xml, xpath, sax

I want to extract below xml data received in string variable to a list. Is it best to use an SAX parser or Xpath and which is quickest way?

It would also be helpful if you can guide me with some code.

**Input String**

```
<TestEventEntity xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<Sid>u34u5i435b4ih5b</Sid>
<UserId>9485924857429857</UserId>
<TestPercentId>4957493574395</TestPercentId>
<TestGroup>test2</TestGroup>
<SessionStartDt>2015-02-17T08:38:18.5179128-06:00</SessionStartDt>
<Event>my Event</Event>
</TestEventEntity>
```

**Expected Output**

[u34u5i435b4ih5b,9485924857429857,4957493574395,test2,2015-02-17T08:38:18.5179128-06:00, my Event]

Comment: If you won't encounter nested tags or don't treat structure information below the root level + 1 in a special way, a sax parser should suffice. However, in that case you probably don't need parsing at all.

Answer (score 0):

For comparison of parsers, [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/689144/4316015). For your purpose SAX looks like the best option.

For the code of SAXParser: You'll need a XML stream or file and a Handler class (described [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/SAXParser.html))

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about performance, but the following code is an easy way to do what you want:

```
File xmlFile = new File("path/to/file.xml");
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(xmlFile);
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
//Get childs of root tag
NodeList elementsUnderRootTag = doc.getElementsByTagName("rootTagName").item(0).getChildNodes();
//Iterating over childs of root node
for (int i = 0; i < elementsUnderRootTag.getLength(); i++) {
    Node child = elementsUnderRootTag.item(i);
    if (child.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
        Element elm = (Element) child;
        System.out.pringln(elm.getTextContent());
    }
}
```

For more information about different kinds of parsing an xml file(or string as well), take a look at [here](http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/java-xml-tutorials/). There is anything you want with running sample codes over there.